# How to use h264_mmal hardware decoder in RaspberryPi 3 in Snappy Ubuntu Core?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, gpu-driver

I have a program that makes use of the h264_mmal hardware accelerated decoder in Raspberry Pi 3. The same executable works fine on the same Raspberry Pi board if the OS is Ubuntu-Mate with gpu_men set to 128M. But If I use Snappy Ubuntu Core, the program cannot get any video frame from MMAL. It shows the following error messages repeatedly:

[h264_mmal @ 0x105bca0] Did not get output frame from MMAL.

[h264_mmal @ 0x105bca0] MMAL error 2 on control port

I have installed all the dependencies such as ffmpeg libs and libraspberrypi0 in Snappy Ubuntu Core. And it cannot work neither in the classic mode nor in the default snappy mode.

Does anyone know if Snappy Ubuntu Core already supports MMAL hardware accelerated decoder in Raspberry Pi 3? And if so, how to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that Ubuntu Core uses some GPU memory, not leaving enough for the `h264_mmal` decoder .

I got a similar issue on my Raspberry Pi Zero W. I increased `gpu_mem` from 128 to 160; that allowed the decoder to run without errors. You may want to  increase it with 16MB steps so to leave as much memory as possible for the OS.